# Unable to execute Laravel artisan commands

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-4

I just installed the latest version of Laravel and tried to run the following command from my Git Bash:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
```

This triggers the following error:

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

I have tried a number of things I found here on this site, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: Just checking; are you in the directory that `artisan` is in (the base Laravel directory)?

Comment: I am in the directory where the laravel project is located, yes.

Comment: Ok, awesome (you'd be surprised how many people would say "no"). I'm assuming that you're using Windows (since you're using Git Bash); I'm still learning about Laravel, and have no experience using it on a Windows system. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175570/how-to-install-laravels-artisan) might be able to help; is your PHP command working properly? Best of luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175570/how-to-install-laravels-artisan

Comment: @ChrisForrence alright, guilty of that. lol.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### tl;dr

Run `composer install` in your project's root folder.

### Explanation

This happens when you create a project by downloading and extracting the [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) repo from GitHub, not by using the Composer command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

In this case the dependencies are not installed, so the `vendor` folder that contains Artisan doesn't exist. Running `composer install` in your project's root folder will install the dependencies `vendor` folder.

For more, see my other [answer on how to install Artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175571/1494454).

### Side note

This is independent from your problem but your Artisan command is a bit deficient. You forgot `=users` (the table name) from the end. Also if you create a table you dont have to specify the table name again with the `--table` option so this command would be enough:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't have artisan. There are two reasons:

1. To be able to run `php artisan <command>` you must be in your project folder, so first move to that folder using the `cd` command, then you can execute the command.
2. You haven't created a *Laravel* project in that folder. [You must create one with Composer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995027/2615737)

Answer (score 3):

Run following composer command in your root folder

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 1):

Run following composer command in your root folder

composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs

It will install gd extension and update the dependencies

Comment: What relation does GD have to Artisan?

Comment: artisan can update the gd extension, and i am not fully sure, but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In your root directory you have **artisan.php** file which is internally triggering **Illuminate\Console\Application::start($app);**

So follow that path and see what is happening. Do you have any output when you run **php artisan** ? That error is usually shown when artisan is not in your path (current directory).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel needs the PHP version 5.5.9. If you have some lower version, you may not get anything executed and it may not throw any error based on you settings.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem. you need to run `composer update` and then run `composer install`