# laravel Could not open input file: artisan (5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I'm new to Laravel ad i have just created new project using [official laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3).

After installing when i run **php artisan migrate** it will showing

> **Could not open input file: artisan** error in console

Listing of commands that i run

1. **composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelDemo**

   which will create new folder laravelDemo
2. **cd laravelDemo**
3. **php artisan migrate**

I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04**

I have already checked [possible duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994590/unable-to-execute-laravel-artisan-commands) but i have installed it throw composer.

Please help Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @Tiger yes i already checked that answer but i have download it from composer as you can see my commands that i run.

Comment: Are you in your project directory ?

Comment: @Tiger yes please look second step.

Comment: run this command `composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: @Tiger still the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128923/discussion-between-binit-ghetiya-and-tiger).

Comment: Are you sure you navigated to the `laravelDemo` project directory with your console after installing laravel?

Comment: yes @Adepoju-CondeAdesegunChris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not figure out what actual problem is but what i did is **deleted** laravelDemo folder and run above command and it worked.

> i have also tried **composer update --no-scripts** which will updated all the composer dependencies successfully.
>
> May be there were some issue in installing the project.

Answer (score 1):

check that the project contains the artisan file, it's a php.

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';



$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);


$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you type the command out of laravelDemo folder.
please go into this folder by running:
cd laravelDemo
and try again.

Answer (score 0):

i my case, i decide to reinstall all my project  and it work fine