# How do I install Laravel/Artisan into an existing Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have an existing Laravel project that doesn't include the entire Laravel framework including Artisan CLI and its dependencies. I would like to do Migrations/Seeding for this existing Laravel project working with Artisan CLI.

What do I have to install/include in the existing Laravel project composer.json to get Laravel/Artisan CLI and its dependencies into an existing Laravel project?

Here is what my composer.json file looks like:

```
"require": {
"illuminate/database": "^8.61",
"illuminate/support": "^8.61",
"illuminate/http": "^8.61",
"illuminate/events": "^8.61",
"sebastiansulinski/string-converter": "^3.0",
"jenssegers/blade": "^1.2",
"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.2.1",
"nesbot/carbon": "^2.22",
"ext-openssl": "*",
"ext-json": "*",
"dyrynda/laravel-efficient-uuid": "^4.3",
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.129",
"ext-curl": "*",
"whichbrowser/parser": "^2.0.42",
"spomky-labs/otphp": "^10.0",
"endroid/qr-code": "^4.3",
"twilio/sdk": "^6.16",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
```

},

Comment: Could you add more details please and provide us with code snippet of screenshot

Comment: Or screenshot *

Comment: You should share your `package.json` to find what you have forgot there. But you can always create a fresh install of Laravel and copy your application's code to the new project. Depends what the code base was before and what you expect Laravel to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175570/how-to-install-laravels-artisan help?

Answer (score -1):

I think the package you are looking for is

```
"illuminate/console"
```

Also make sure you have **artisan** file in you project root directory.
If there is no **artisan** file then you need to create one, here is the content for the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Artisan Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When we run the console application, the current CLI command will be
| executed in this console and the response sent back to a terminal
| or another output device for the developers. Here goes nothing!
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shutdown The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once Artisan has finished running, we will fire off the shutdown events
| so that any final work may be done by the application before we shut
| down the process. This is the last thing to happen to the request.
|
*/

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

Comment: I added the package and the Artisan file to project root. This is my error now trying to run a command against the Artisan CLI:


C:\xampp\htdocs\Project>php artisan list

In RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php line 48:

  Directory name must not be empty.

Comment: It seems some essential directories are missing. Try to debug the error, look more dipper in error stack trace

Answer (score -1):

Go to the folder application using cd command on your cmd or terminal

Run composer install on your cmd or terminal

Copy .env.example file to .env on the root folder. You can

type copy .env.example .env if using command prompt Windows
or cp .env.example .env if using terminal, Ubuntu

Open your .env file and change the database name (DB_DATABASE) to whatever you have, username (DB_USERNAME) and password (DB_PASSWORD) field correspond to your configuration.

Run php artisan key:generate

Run php artisan migrate

Run php artisan serve

Go to http://localhost:8000/